# CMake fails when building OpenCV (Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, opencv, ubuntu, cmake

I'm trying to build OpenCV with CMake but when I build it, some stuff goes wrong and I have no idea what to do to fix it.

So the question basically is: How do I fix it?

```
user@BEL-PC:~/opencv/build$ cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF ..
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
-- The C compiler identification is GNU
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
CMake Error: your CXX compiler: "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND" was not found.   Please set CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to a valid compiler path or name.
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FSIGNED_CHAR
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeCXXInformation.cmake:37 (GET_FILENAME_COMPONENT):
  get_filename_component called with incorrect number of arguments
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:2 (PROJECT)


CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FSIGNED_CHAR - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FSIGNED_CHAR
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FSIGNED_CHAR - Success
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Could NOT find ZLIB (missing:  ZLIB_LIBRARY ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- Looking for fseeko
-- Looking for fseeko - found
-- Looking for unistd.h
-- Looking for unistd.h - found
-- Looking for sys/types.h
-- Looking for sys/types.h - found
-- Looking for stdint.h
-- Looking for stdint.h - found
-- Looking for stddef.h
-- Looking for stddef.h - found
-- Check size of off64_t
-- Check size of off64_t - failed
-- Could NOT find TIFF (missing:  TIFF_LIBRARY TIFF_INCLUDE_DIR) 
CMake Error: your CXX compiler: "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND" was not found.   Please set CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to a valid compiler path or name.
-- Looking for assert.h
-- Looking for assert.h - found
-- Looking for fcntl.h
-- Looking for fcntl.h - found
-- Looking for io.h
-- Looking for io.h - not found
-- Looking for jbg_newlen
-- Looking for jbg_newlen - not found
-- Looking for mmap
-- Looking for mmap - found
-- Looking for search.h
-- Looking for search.h - found
-- Looking for string.h
-- Looking for string.h - found
-- Looking for unistd.h
-- Looking for unistd.h - found
-- Could NOT find JPEG (missing:  JPEG_LIBRARY JPEG_INCLUDE_DIR) 
CMake Error: your CXX compiler: "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND" was not found.   Please set CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to a valid compiler path or name.
-- Found JPEG: libjpeg 
-- Could NOT find Jasper (missing:  JASPER_LIBRARY JASPER_INCLUDE_DIR) 
CMake Error: your CXX compiler: "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND" was not found.   Please set CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to a valid compiler path or name.
-- Found ZLIB: zlib (found version "1.2.7")
-- Could NOT find PNG (missing:  PNG_LIBRARY PNG_PNG_INCLUDE_DIR) 
CMake Error: your CXX compiler: "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND" was not found.   Please set CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to a valid compiler path or name.
CMake Error: your CXX compiler: "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND" was not found.   Please set CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to a valid compiler path or name.
-- Looking for semaphore.h
-- Looking for semaphore.h - found
-- checking for module 'gtk+-2.0'
--   package 'gtk+-2.0' not found
-- checking for module 'gthread-2.0'
--   package 'gthread-2.0' not found
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-base-0.10'
--   package 'gstreamer-base-0.10' not found
-- checking for module 'libdc1394-2'
--   package 'libdc1394-2' not found
-- checking for module 'libdc1394'
--   package 'libdc1394' not found
-- checking for module 'libv4l1'
--   package 'libv4l1' not found
-- Looking for linux/videodev.h
-- Looking for linux/videodev.h - not found
-- Looking for linux/videodev2.h
-- Looking for linux/videodev2.h - found
-- Looking for sys/videoio.h
-- Looking for sys/videoio.h - not found
-- checking for module 'libavcodec'
--   package 'libavcodec' not found
-- checking for module 'libavformat'
--   package 'libavformat' not found
-- checking for module 'libavutil'
--   package 'libavutil' not found
-- checking for module 'libswscale'
--   package 'libswscale' not found
-- Looking for libavformat/avformat.h
-- Looking for libavformat/avformat.h - not found
-- Looking for ffmpeg/avformat.h
-- Looking for ffmpeg/avformat.h - not found
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeCXXInformation.cmake:37 (GET_FILENAME_COMPONENT):
  get_filename_component called with incorrect number of arguments
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:2 (PROJECT)


CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python (found suitable version "2.7.3", required is "2.0")
-- Could NOT find PythonLibs (missing:  PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS) (Required is at least version "2.7.3")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named numpy.distutils
-- Found apache ant 1.8.2: /usr/bin/ant
-- Found JNI: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64/libjawt.so 
-- Could NOT find OPENCL (missing:  OPENCL_LIBRARY OPENCL_INCLUDE_DIR) 
CMake Error: your CXX compiler: "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND" was not found.   Please set CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to a valid compiler path or name.
CMake Error: your CXX compiler: "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND" was not found.   Please set CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to a valid compiler path or name.
CMake Error: your CXX compiler: "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND" was not found.   Please set CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to a valid compiler path or name.
CMake Error: your CXX compiler: "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND" was not found.   Please set CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to a valid compiler path or name.
CMake Error: your CXX compiler: "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND" was not found.   Please set CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to a valid compiler path or name.
CMake Error: your CXX compiler: "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND" was not found.   Please set CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to a valid compiler path or name.
CMake Error: your CXX compiler: "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND" was not found.   Please set CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to a valid compiler path or name.
CMake Error: your CXX compiler: "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND" was not found.   Please set CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to a valid compiler path or name.
CMake Error: your CXX compiler: "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND" was not found.   Please set CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to a valid compiler path or name.
CMake Error: your CXX compiler: "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND" was not found.   Please set CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to a valid compiler path or name.
CMake Error: your CXX compiler: "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND" was not found.   Please set CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to a valid compiler path or name.
CMake Error: your CXX compiler: "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND" was not found.   Please set CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to a valid compiler path or name.
CMake Error: your CXX compiler: "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND" was not found.   Please set CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to a valid compiler path or name.
CMake Error: your CXX compiler: "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND" was not found.   Please set CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to a valid compiler path or name.
CMake Error: your CXX compiler: "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND" was not found.   Please set CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to a valid compiler path or name.
CMake Error: your CXX compiler: "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND" was not found.   Please set CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to a valid compiler path or name.
CMake Error: your CXX compiler: "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND" was not found.   Please set CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to a valid compiler path or name.
CMake Error: your CXX compiler: "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND" was not found.   Please set CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to a valid compiler path or name.
CMake Error: your CXX compiler: "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND" was not found.   Please set CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to a valid compiler path or name.
CMake Error: your CXX compiler: "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND" was not found.   Please set CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to a valid compiler path or name.
CMake Error: your CXX compiler: "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND" was not found.   Please set CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to a valid compiler path or name.
CMake Error: your CXX compiler: "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND" was not found.   Please set CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to a valid compiler path or name.
-- 
-- General configuration for OpenCV 2.4.6.1 =====================================
--   Version control:               2.4.6.1-176-g1c55096
-- 
--   Platform:
--     Host:                        Linux 3.5.0-37-generic x86_64
--     CMake:                       2.8.7
--     CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
--     CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/make
--     Configuration:               Release
-- 
--   C/C++:
--     Built as dynamic libs?:      NO
--     C++ Compiler:                CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND
--     C++ flags (Release):         
--     C++ flags (Debug):           
--     C Compiler:                  /usr/bin/gcc
--     C flags (Release):           -fsigned-char -O3 -DNDEBUG 
--     C flags (Debug):             -fsigned-char -g 
--     Linker flags (Release):      
--     Linker flags (Debug):        
--     Precompiled headers:         NO
-- 
--   OpenCV modules:
--     To be built:                 core imgproc flann highgui features2d calib3d ml video objdetect contrib photo legacy gpu nonfree java stitching superres ts videostab
--     Disabled:                    world
--     Disabled by dependency:      -
--     Unavailable:                 androidcamera ocl python
-- 
--   GUI: 
--     QT:                          NO
--     GTK+ 2.x:                    NO
--     GThread :                    NO
--     GtkGlExt:                    NO
--     OpenGL support:              NO
-- 
--   Media I/O: 
--     ZLib:                        zlib (ver 1.2.7)
--     JPEG:                        libjpeg (ver 62)
--     PNG:                         build (ver 1.5.12)
--     TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.0.2)
--     JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 1.900.1)
--     OpenEXR:                     build (ver 1.7.1)
-- 
--   Video I/O:
--     DC1394 1.x:                  NO
--     DC1394 2.x:                  NO
--     FFMPEG:                      NO
--       codec:                     NO
--       format:                    NO
--       util:                      NO
--       swscale:                   NO
--       gentoo-style:              NO
--     GStreamer:                   NO
--     OpenNI:                      NO
--     OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules:  NO
--     PvAPI:                       NO
--     GigEVisionSDK:               NO
--     UniCap:                      NO
--     UniCap ucil:                 NO
--     V4L/V4L2:                    NO/YES
--     XIMEA:                       NO
--     Xine:                        NO
-- 
--   Other third-party libraries:
--     Use IPP:                     NO
--     Use Eigen:                   NO
--     Use TBB:                     NO
--     Use OpenMP:                  NO
--     Use GCD                      NO
--     Use Concurrency              NO
--     Use C=:                      NO
--     Use Cuda:                    NO
--     Use OpenCL:                  NO
-- 
--   Python:
--     Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python (ver 2.7.3)
-- 
--   Java:
--     ant:                         /usr/bin/ant (ver 1.8.2)
--     JNI:                         /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_21/include /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_21/include/linux /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_21/include
--     Java tests:                  YES
-- 
--   Documentation:
--     Build Documentation:         NO
--     Sphinx:                      NO
--     PdfLaTeX compiler:           NO
-- 
--   Tests and samples:
--     Tests:                       YES
--     Performance tests:           YES
--     C/C++ Examples:              NO
-- 
--   Install path:                  /usr/local
-- 
--   cvconfig.h is in:              /home/user/opencv/build
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------
-- 
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Comment: `CMake Error: your CXX compiler: "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND" was not found.   Please set CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to a valid compiler path or name.` This sound you haven't got a C++ compiler. `sudo apt-get install build-essential` will install it. Then there are a number of other libraries not found

Comment: and why don't you use opencv from the repository?

Comment: Your first comment fixed my problem. I'm so happy it was just a simple mistake like this. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to hetepeperfan I was able to fix my problem. It turns out I was simply missing a C++ compiler.

After running `sudo apt-get install build-essential` and cleaning up my build folder and rerunning cmake the problem was fixed.